# How run the pgadmin4 docker image in the cloud foundry environment?

Tags: docker, gunicorn, cloud-foundry, pgadmin-4, connection-refused

Our company uses the cloud foundry for the cloud services. Currently i need the docker container solution to analyse the connected databases in the cloud foundry context. I try to deploy with cf tool the docker container of pgadmin in dockerhub using

The versions 7.5 and 7.0 with following dockers

https://hub.docker.com/layers/dpage/pgadmin4/7.5/images/sha256-6cb9dbbe4bf7a5fe148ccba43bf241e34e26b36d490b42f17e57f3267f8e17f5?context=explore

https://hub.docker.com/layers/dpage/pgadmin4/7/images/sha256-6cb9dbbe4bf7a5fe148ccba43bf241e34e26b36d490b42f17e57f3267f8e17f5?context=explore
But this attempt failed.

Details:

First, I set the default password and default e-mail

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
```

Otherwise the Startup was aborted.

Second, if I tried to push out of the box without any environments related to tcp ip, the connection refused error occurred sent by gunicorn

I set then listen address 0.0.0.0 with default port 8080  with the variables

```
PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT
```

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.5/container_deployment.html#environment-variables

If i try to deploy the pgadmin docker image, I see in console log during start, that pgadmin initialisation starts on given host 0.0.0.0 with given port 8080 with gunicorn.

And then the connection refused errors are shown on the host 10.xx.yy.yx on the ports 80 and 443.

For example:

[CELL.0] failed to make TCP connection to 10.xx.xz.yz:80: dial tcp 10.xx.xz.yz:80: connect: connection refused

I was looking for the other possible  environment settings in pgadmin and set a lot of envs related to tcp ip stack by PGADMIN_CONFIG prefix. I analyzed the python source code of pgadmin4 , the shell scripts and Dockerfile finally.

I found out, that ports 80 and 443 are exposed in docker container by default . I look at others envs by gunicorn https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/config.py

But currenlty it is impossible to use the official docker image. If i select other images from docker hub of pgadmin, i can use these images, but these docker images use the downloading from FTP directory and set other ports top be exposed.

Of course, I can use these other images of pgadmin4 or i can use other solution for example Cloud dbeaver docker Images.

Our department prefers the pgadmin way.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to resolve this issue using dpage pgadmin4 image?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to deploy pgadmin4 ui to CF with a specific image using below manifest. Issue is with latest image. Hope this helps

```
applications:
  - name: sandbox-ilm-pgadmin
    docker:
      image: dpage/pgadmin4:2023-05-02-1
    instances: 1
    health-check-type: process
    env:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: sandbox-pgadmin@ilm.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: Sandbox123*
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
```